# ConTeXt: Heading text surrounded by lines

Tags: sectioning, context, metafun

I'd like to replicate this heading style in ConTeXt:

[image]

The closest I've come is surrounding a centered text with `\thinrule`s but those are at the baseline of the text instead of horizontally centered around the text:

`\centeraligned{\thinrule SKILLS \thinrule}`

Does someone have a solution? I'm sure it's possible with MetaFun but I haven't quite understood enough of that yet.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can create raised rules with the `\blackrule` command. The correct width for the rules can be calculated when you measure the width of the `section` text with the `\dowithnextbox` command.

```
\define\SectionTextCommand
  {\dowithnextbox
     {\beginhbox
        \blackrule[width=\dimexpr(\hsize-\nextboxwd-2\emwidth)/2\relax,height=0.8ex,depth=-0.6ex,color=middlecyan]%
        \quad
        \copy\nextbox
        \quad
        \blackrule[width=\dimexpr(\hsize-\nextboxwd-2\emwidth)/2\relax,height=0.8ex,depth=-0.6ex,color=middlecyan]%
      \endhbox}
     \hbox}

\setuphead
  [subject]
  [textstyle={\setcharactercasing[WORD]\ssa},
   textcommand=\SectionTextCommand]

\starttext

\subject{Skills}

\stoptext
```

Another method is to use the `filler` mechanism to place rules at the left and right of the text which take the available space without the need to calculate it.

```
\definefiller
  [SectionRule]
  [alternative=rule,
   color=middlecyan,
   height=0.8ex,
   depth=-0.6ex]

\definefiller
  [SectionLeftRule]
  [SectionRule]
  [left=\zerowidthnobreakspace,
   right=\quad]

\definefiller
  [SectionRightRule]
  [SectionRule]
  [left=\quad,
   right=\zerowidthnobreakspace]

\setuphead
  [subject]
  [%align=middle,
   textstyle={\setcharactercasing[WORD]\ssa},
   textcommand=\groupedcommand{\filler[SectionLeftRule]}{\filler[SectionRightRule]}]

\starttext

\subject{Skills}

\stoptext
```